# Build Reactjs blank page and not generated other pages

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am newbie in reactjs, just create my first reactjs app, I want to make production version, and used this command:

```
npm run build
```

But in generated just a blank index.html file, why? Because I have many routes , how can I access other pages? and why index is blank?

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "express": "latest",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.1",
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.1.0",
    "semantic-ui-css": "^2.4.1",
    "semantic-ui-react": "^0.88.1",
    "socket.io": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "universal-cookie": "^4.0.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: you need to set home path in package.json,can you provide you package.json file?

Comment: @JatinParmar added

Comment: just one more thing how you serv you production build?, i mean how you run index.html? is it hosted some where or you are running directly using browser?

Comment: @JatinParmar runing directly using chrome, in my local machine, not uploaded

Comment: i have added my answer ,please check ,this may help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to add

```
"homepage": "http://mywebsite.com/relativepath",
```

in your package.json file  if its hosted somewhre on server.
or to run it locally you need to type following command

```
npm install -g serve
serve -s build
```

or you when using react-router you can set

**EDIT**

```
"homepage": "."
```

to work it locally

for more info [read here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/)

Comment: I don't have a domain yet, how should write in homepage? relativepath? what this mean?

Comment: you just need to install serve using npm and then just run serve -s build

Comment: `bash: serve: command not found`but `npm install -g serve` was successfull, any idea?

Comment: i think serve is not installed correctly ,you can confrim by using 'npm list -g'

Comment: just to confrim,i have created a test app and install serve package and its working fine.

Comment: It's already installed, but not run serve -s build, I am trying to update `npm` and clear cache

Comment: are you running it from you project root folder?

Comment: Yes, where `package.json` file is.

Comment: can you provide any access to your project folder? like some fiddle ,including all you files?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206704/discussion-between-jatin-parmar-and-tour-travel).

Comment: I don't use react-router but I add "homepage": "." into package.json and it just works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
npm run build -- --profile
```

Comment: It still same index.html blank in build folder